# Accept all cookies automatically in Google Chrome Incognito mode

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, private-browsing

Is there a way to force Google Chrome to accept all cookies automatically when in incognito mode?  I'd prefer the solution to **not** require installation of extensions because ideally this would work in both desktop Google Chrome as well as the Google Chrome Android app, and the latter is (as of today IIRC) is crippled by disallowing use of extensions.

Update: My question is specifically to accept all cookies in incognito **without prompting with an "Is it ok to accept cookies?" prompts**.  I reason that accepting the cookies is ok to do, because I'm going to just close the incognito window straight away after a short time period of browsing to a website.

Comment: What's the point of incognito mode if you're not incognito?

Comment: I've updated the question with my reasoning for this. My use-case for using incognito mode to allow the website to store cookies all it wants, because I'm going to close the incognito window anyway. Isn't it the case that any stored cookies will be deleted at that time, and if so, then accepting the cookies should be fine as long as Chrome does not force me make the prompt disappear by having to answer it either with a "yes" or a "no" answer to that "is it ok to store cookies?" prompts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the laws that have driven those annoying pop-ups is that people "know" the cookies they're accepting. This means the sites are designed to show those messages and require you to accept or make choices.

Outside using a plug-in, you can't do this.

A brief search of the internet showed a few plug-ins that claim to do what you want. Have you tried any of these? They may not be the solution you want, but they are the solution you have.

Comment: "Have you tried any of these?" No. I would have to trust that extension, and I have no way to verify that type of trust without expensive-to-me testing evaluations. But, thank you for your answer: At this particular moment in time, I have to agree with you, until someone can provide an answer that does not involve installation of extensions. Will mark this as The Answer for now.